# Expanding parent's height to its children's heights

Tags: height, children, parents

Is it possible to expand parents height to its children's height in CSS? Or is there any trick to handle that? Or just JavaScript?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child child1"></div>
    <div class="child child2"></div>
    <div class="child child3"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child child1"></div>
    <div class="child child2"></div>
    <div class="child child3"></div>
</div>
```

Additional info, the 3 children boxes are put onto each other, AND there are many-many parent div boxes under each other, so would be important to force the height of the parent div boxes.

CSS style something like that, but not working.

```
parent  {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
margin-left: -50vw;
margin-right: -50vw;
border: none;
border: solid 6px green;}

.child {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
border: solid 2px red;}

.child1 {z-index: 100;}

.child2 {z-index: 200;}

.child3 {z-index: 300;}
```

Thanks in advance!
FF

Comment: So the children are overflowing the parent?

Comment: If so, does changing to `overflow: visible` for the parent solve your issue?

Comment: I tried with visible value of property overflow, and I took this property out as well ... no changes.

Comment: How about taking out the `overflow` property from the parent (the default is `visible` anyway) and changing to `min-height: 100px`?

Comment: Taking out overflow property didn't help, and min-height: 100px neither. If I set the min-height 100px, parents boxes overlapping each other if the height of the children boxes bigger.